# Ruby on rails data pass to javascript become HTMLDIVELEMENT

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass database value retrieved by ruby to javascript,to handle some div display.

Strange thing is,when I pass number(means I retrieve number from database and pass to js),it works fine,as follow,this load_web is a short int.

```
if (<%= @device.load_web %>==0)
{ $('.somediv').find('input,textarea,select').attr('disabled',true); }
});
```

But when I try same method,passing string to js,it returns me HTMLDIVElement,which is very strange.

```
if(<%= @device.brand%>=="apple")
    {
    alert("apple"); 
    }
    else
    {
    alert(<%= @device.brand %>);
    }
```

The data in my database for this colum is "apple",but the logic falls into else loop,and give me a "object HTMLDIVElement" message.

Why is so?

**EDIT:**
I try use alert(<%= @device.brand %>.innerHTML);
and get the following message:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that erb tags just insert the result of the ruby code in them into your html template. So unless `@device.brand` is returning some properly formatted javascript (or a number), you probably want to wrap it in strings. Try this:

```
if("<%= @device.brand%>"=="apple")
    {
    alert("apple"); 
    }
    else
    {
    alert("<%= @device.brand %>");
    }
```

Comment: I try change according to your solution,then the whole if statement not executed,neither go if nor else,(previously I go to else state).so I feel its not the quotation marks' problem

Comment: Was there any error messages in your javascript console?

Comment: thank you,Today I try again use " " instead of ' ',it works now!

Comment: I'm sure the choice of quotes does not matter to javascript. Glad it solved your problem.